# Command to list all file extensions in directory and subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I need a list of all the file types I have in a directory with many subfolders. Easy way to do this in the command line?

I've tried creating a batch file script using variations of the following:

```
@echo off & setlocal

for %%I in (*.*) do (
    set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1
)

set ext[
```

The above script successfully returns the file extensions in the current directory. But I'm having trouble modifying this script to return the file extensions in all sub folders.

Edit for additional information:

I am a noob at this so have no clue what I'm doing, here was my workflow:

1. created my .bat file in notepad using the script above, copied and pasted as is
2. stuck my .bat file in the parent directory where I want to search for the file extensions
3. in the command line, used pushd to set the working directory to the parent directory
4. in the command line, typed the name of the .bat file to run it

did I make any errors in my steps?

Comment: See what `for /?` tells you about its `/R` switch.

Comment: @Stephan when I modify the script to '''for /R in (*.*) do  '''I get the error '''(*.*) was unexpected at this time. ''' Am I modifying the script incorrectly?

Comment: You forgot the metavariale: `for /R %%I in (*) do ...`

Comment: ohh I thought I was supposed to replace %%I with /R... oops. will try that and report back.

Comment: @Stephan this worked, thank you

Comment: @plast1cd0nk3y Please note that `for /R %%I in (*) do` ignores files with hidden attribute set. The result could be inaccurate on directory tree containing also hidden files. The single command line solution `@(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @set /A ext[%%~xI]+=1) & set ext[` counts also the file extensions of hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use `dir` and capture a full file listing, then use your `for` loop over the results:

```
@echo off
setlocal

dir /S /A-D /B /W *.* > "%TEMP%\files.txt"

for /F %%I in (%TEMP%\files.txt) do (
    set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1
)

del "%TEMP%\files.txt"

set ext[
```

In this case, I'm telling `dir` to ignore directories, and reduce the listing to just filenames (and no summary).

Comment: That batch file does not work if `%TEMP%` expands to a folder path containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` because of not enclosing `%TEMP%\files.txt` in `"`. The command line with `for /F` is additionally wrong as missing with usage of `"%TEMP%\files.txt"` the option `usebackq` and definitely missing also `delims=` for processing also file names correct containing one or more spaces in fully qualified file name. `@(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do @set /A ext[%%~xI]+=1) & set ext[` is the single line doing the entire task.

Comment: when I run this, the script just loads forever and never actually returns anything... am I supposed to modify this script in any way/replace any of the variables? I just copied and pasted as is in my bat file, set my directory in the command line to the location of the file (which is also the parent directory where I'm searching for the file extensions), but am I supposed to specify the directory I want to search in, in the bat script?

Comment: @BrendaThompson The overall behavior is unchanged from your original script, it enumerates files starting from the current working directory. How big is your directory tree? Running against a sample tree with 62k files took about 30 seconds. If performance is a major concern, using batch files might not be the best tool.

Comment: @joshpoley There is still the problem with `for /F %%I in (%TEMP%\files.txt) do (` not working if `%TEMP%` expands to a folder path containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. There is still the problem with file names with path inside `files.txt` not correct processed on containing a space. The correct command line with unnecessary usage of a file would be `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%TEMP%\files.txt") do set /A ext[%%~xI]+=1`. Faster with lots of file system accesses avoided would be the usage of the single command line solution posted in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.* ') do (
```

The `dir` subcommand uses `/s` (with subdirectories) `/b` (basic list - names only, no headers/footers) `/a-d` (no directorynames) and delivers a list of names in the form `d:\path\filename.ext`.

The `for /f` processes that list in memory, delivering each line in turn to `%%I`. The `"delims="` turns off the default tokenising.

See 'for /?` from the prompt, or thousands of examples on SO for documentation.

Comment: It may not be clear, or logical, but the period in `*.*` does not mean a literal period character must be present to match. Therefore `*.*` is not needed in this example, because the `dir` command returns every file. I thought I'd mention it, because, without knowing the exact task, a potential issue may arise, because it is feasible that fiiles without extensions could be located within the recursed subdirectories.